# What's the meaning of @ tag on proxy dll?

Tags: dll, msvc

In proxy dll in .def file I can see the following notation:

```
_CreateFrameInfo=PROXY__CreateFrameInfo @1
```

Others use in the following format:

```
 _AIL_3D_position@16 = vcruntime140_._AIL_3D_position@16
```

What is the meaning of @ tag in that notation?

Also, I have run the Dependency Walker on that program. It returned Hint: 1 (0x0001), 5(0x0005), etc. Are these related? There are less hints than functions though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [*name decoration*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/name-decoration). Specifically in this case, it denotes `__stdcall` functions which accept the indicated number of bytes as stack arguments.

The number at the end of the export definition (after the space delimiter) is used to specifty [the *ordinal* of the export](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports).

Comment: It it not clear from the documentaion, whether that decoration numbers are related to the number of bytes in the arguments of the described functions or can be any number, i.e. the reference number of the function. Saw it used both ways in proxy dlls.

Comment: @Irbis77 see update